# "Троглодит" в значении "обжора"

Tags: значение-слов

Слово "троглодит" означает пещерного человека или, в переносном смысле, невежду. Может ли оно означать того, кто много поедает (обжору)?

Например:
Этот фермер после загона скота садится за стол и съедает все, что было подано - настоящий троглодит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Большой толковый словарь русского языка Кузнецова:
[**троглоди́т**](https://gufo.me/dict/kuznetsov/%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82), -а; м. [греч. *trōglodytēs* — живущий в норе или пещере]
1. *Антроп*. Первобытный пещерный человек.
2. *Разг.* О грубом, некультурном человеке.
**3.** О том, кто много и неуёмно ест; **об обжоре.**

*Ну ты и троглодит! Обжора прям какой-то!* (С. Жихарев)

*Троглодит, это было прозвище. Так окрестили своего бездомного собрата его товарищи по несчастью. А все из-за того, что он мог употреблять в пищу всякую гадость, вплоть до резины, древесной коры, травы, и даже мог спокойно погрызть застывшую смолу. <…> Вот таким вот образом Троглодит оказался единственным в этом роде обжорой* (С. Бугримов).